# Is it possible to know derived object size in base class?

Tags: c++

I have requirement that some family of objects of their own derived classes have to be initialized in special memory slots with placement new operator. All of them will be derived from common base.
The problem is that there is a size limit for such object.
So I would like to put static assertion on derived object size but I do not want to bother with static assertion in each descendant.
My question is:  Is there is any way to put this assertion into the base or use any other trick in order to check the size outside the derived class declaration?
It is acceptable to design base class as a template.

Comment: What about overwriting the new operators (new, array, placement) in the base class?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to be a good idea!

Comment: Uh... nope. Size is passed to new() operator in runtime.

Comment: Essential to this is: What will happen if the object is too large / why do you worry about it? If "all" that happens is that the application crashes when a too large object is inserted into the list (and you can clearly make sure that is the case by having a "guard" that, is checked against and you abort the program if it happens - or by using your own placement new that fails if the object is too large), then the problem is for the programmer who made a too large object to solve...

Comment: It is embedded and highly reliable software. Such a bug as slightly too large object can exist for a long time, pass many tests and suddenly make a huge mess when million devices is on the market.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like yet another use case for [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
constexpr std::size_t limit = 42;

template <typename Derived>
class Base {
  ~Base() {
    static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= limit, "Derived class is too big.");
  }
};

class Foo : Base<Foo> {};
```

Of course, if you need a common base class you can inject one below the CRTP size check:

```
class Base {
  // ...
};

constexpr std::size_t limit = 42;

template <typename Derived>
class SizeCheck : public Base {
  ~SizeCheck() {
    static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= limit, "Derived class is too big.");
  }
};

class Foo : SizeCheck<Foo> {};
```

and if your goal is not merely to save some keystrokes, but to defend against people who are actively *trying* to break the check:

```
template <typename>
class SizeCheck;

class Base {
  // ...
private:
  // Only allow SizeCheck to derive from Base
  ~Base() = default;
  template <typename>
  friend class SizeCheck;
};

constexpr std::size_t limit = 42;

template <typename Derived>
class SizeCheck : public Base {
private:
  // Only allow Derived to derive from SizeCheck<Derived>
  friend Derived;
  ~SizeCheck() {
    static_assert(sizeof(Derived) <= limit, "Derived class is too big.");

    // Ensure that Derived is actually derived from SizeCheck
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<SizeCheck, Derived>(),
                  "Parameter to SizeCheck must be derived from SizeCheck.");

    // Require Derived to be final so that no one can sidestep 
    // the size check. (Uses C++14 std::is_final)
    static_assert(std::is_final<Derived>(),
                  "Nice try; parameter to SizeCheck must be final.");
  }
};
```

This is all getting a bit twisted. The size of classes derived from `Base` isn't really the issue, it's the possibility of trying to emplace an object that is too large into your statically sized buffers. It may be simpler to approach the issue from the other end by defending the buffers instead of restricting the derived classes ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e5d24e2d1a10f25)):

```
struct placement_delete {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T* ptr) {
    ptr->~T();
  }
};

template <typename T>
using placement_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, placement_delete>;

class Base {
  // ...
};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Align = 0>
class buffer {
public:
  template <typename T, typename...Args>
  placement_ptr<T> emplace(Args&&...args) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>(),
                  "Only classes derived from Base can go in a buffer.");
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(space_),
                  "Type is too big for buffer.");
    static_assert(alignof(decltype(space_)) % alignof(T) == 0,
                  "Buffer alignment is insufficient for type.");
    return placement_ptr<T>{::new(&space_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
  }
private:
  typename std::conditional<!Align,
    typename std::aligned_storage<N>::type,
    typename std::aligned_storage<N, Align>::type
  >::type space_;
};
```

Comment: But I think there is nothing stopping someone from then doing `class Bar : public Foo;` and thus bypassing the desired effect...

Comment: And nothing stopping people from doing `class Bar : public Base<Foo>`.

Comment: Looks very nice but using this we are losing the common base class. In my question I wrote that base class can be a template but now I see that it is problematic. All objects have to be available via pointer to the base...

Comment: @ardabro Simple enough - inject a common base below the CRTP size checking class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that the base-class can directly know the size of a derived class - to do so would require knowing the contents and datalayout of the derived class, which would require that the class is in the same compilation unit - and you probably need to play with templates or macros to make sure it happens.

You could override the `operator new` for the baseclass - which will also work for all derived classes that don't themselves override the `operator new`. There are ways in which you can find out, such as using a virtual function that returns `sizeof(*this)` (but that requires the object is already created - you can't call it from the constructor or before construction, so if you want to use placement new, that won't work).

You can of course, if you are in control of the source code, do `static_assert(sizeof(someDerivedClass) > some_value)` - but that's not guaraneteed to not be broken by someone who wishes to do so.