# Determining largest derived class at compile time

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have a class `Base`, which has `N` children, `Derived0, Derived1, ... ,DerivedN`. I'm trying to create a pool allocator for objects inheriting from `Base`, and the implementation relies on knowing the size of the largest child of `Base`, since the pools much each be large enough to contain one of those objects. Here's a simple example with trivial classes and `N = 2`. In reality, `N` may be larger and `Base`'s children may not be simple POD classes.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

class Derived0 : public Base {
    int a;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    int a, b;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    int a, b, c;
};
```

So let's say that I want to create a buffer large enough to store 10 children. I've been banging my head on this for a while, and this is all I can come up with:

```
static const size_t NUMBER_OF_POOLS = 10;

static const size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE =
    sizeof(Derived0) > sizeof(Derived1) ?
        sizeof(Derived0) > sizeof(Derived2) ?
            sizeof(Derived0) :
            sizeof(Derived2) :
        sizeof(Derived1) > sizeof(Derived2) ?
            sizeof(Derived1) :
            sizeof(Derived2);

char buffer[NUMBER_OF_POOLS * LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE];
```

This works, but it's pretty easy to see how this gets pretty cluttered as `N` starts to grow. Is there any scalable way to implement this, where you don't need to manually build a nested "unary tree" (for lack of a better term) which grows into a giant mess as `N` increases?

Here are the constraints/environment I'm working with:

- The size of the largest child **must** be known at compile time.
- C++03 compatibility is necessary. I'm interested in *any* suggestions (C++11 welcome!) in the interest of curiosity, but I'll ultimately be building this on a compiler without C++11 support. I understand that C++11 added support for unions with non-POD members, so I was thinking that you might be able to clean up the interface a bit using that.
- This will only be built using GCC, so GCC extensions are technically an option.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: And you expect this to work only for certain classes that you know about, or "any class derived from base"? And I think this is similar to a question asked a couple of weeks back about "size of derived class". I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I'm affraid that your current solution might not be portable:  the size of the largest derived could cause bad alignement (segfault on some implementations) for some elements !

Comment: start with a `constexpr` function that returns the maximum of all arguments.  On C++03, you're probably going to be using enums

Comment: Not exactly the same but:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356406/is-it-possible-to-know-derived-object-size-in-base-class

Comment: @MatsPetersson Either way would be fine. It would be awesome if the whole thing was automatic and newly derived classes would be considered at compile-time, but I have a feeling that this might not be possible. If I had to manually add each derived class to the lookup "structure" (however it's implemented) that would be fine.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for the reminder! My basic implementation could definitely lead to issues. I think this is a known consideration for pool allocation, so I'm sure I can figure out some way around this with a bit of searching.

Comment: Why not simply reserve a fixed number of bytes, and use your own `operator new`. If number of bytes "not enough" for some particular use-case, increase it. It would really only be a problem if your derived objects are enormous, and you need to reserve a very large region (but you still need the size of the largest object times max number of objects, so you can't really get away from reserving that much memory either way)

Comment: @MatsPetersson The memory pools are being implemented on an embedded system where memory is at a premium. The current plan is to arbitrarily allocate more memory than is required and write unit tests verifying that every object can fit in a pool,  but I'd eventually like to minimize the wasted space in each pool. This is the case when the pool is _exactly_ the size of the largest object that will ever live inside it, which was the motivation for my question.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your code by introducing a helper macro, resulting better code format. When a new derived class is added, just insert a `STATIC_MAX(sizeof(...` line and add a `)`. This works in C++03.

```
#define STATIC_MAX(a, b)  ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

static const size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE =
    STATIC_MAX(sizeof(Derived0),
    STATIC_MAX(sizeof(Derived1),
    STATIC_MAX(sizeof(Derived2),
               0)));
```

And if C++1x compiler is an option, you can use "variadic template" and "constexpr function" to get a more simple solution. When a new derived class is added, just insert the class name as template parameter in the last line.

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr T static_max(T a, T b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
static constexpr T static_max(T a, Ts... bs) {
    return static_max(a, static_max(bs...));
}

template <typename... Ts>
constexpr size_t max_sizeof() {
    return static_max(sizeof(Ts)...);
};

static constexpr size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE =
    max_sizeof<Derived0, Derived1, Derived2>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) and take its size:

```
    sizeof (boost::variant< Derived0, Derived1, Derived2 > )
```

This will return the size of the largest element.

By the way, it could also simplify your buffer management, by making it a buffer of this variant, and indexing directly the right element.  The good news is that boost takes then care of alignment requirements:

```
    typedef boost::variant< Derived0, Derived1, Derived2 > DerivedVar; 
    DerivedVar buffer[NUMBER_OF_POOLS];
```

Comment: @AndyG, It works under GCC 4.9.1, but I don't know whether it guaranted

Comment: @gomons: both [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/) fairly explicitly state that the size of a union is equal to the size of the largest type in the union.

Comment: I mentioned this in response to @gomons, but unions won't work in C++03  if the classes are not POD types. I feel dumb for using POD types in my example, but I need the approach to support non-POD classes as well. This blurb is from cppreference:

_Unions cannot contain a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, or destructor)._

That only mentions those "special" functions, but any union member with a non-default constructor won't compile in GCC 4.9.2 when compiling against the C++03 standard.

Comment: I tested it, incorrect answer,  `std::cout << "Size of variant: " << sizeof (boost::variant<Derived0,Derived1,Derived2>) << std::endl; std::cout << "Size of Derived2: " << sizeof(Derived2) << std::endl;` returns me `Size of variant: 20 Size of Derived2: 16`.

Comment: I think you need extract size of variant class from `sizeof (boost::variant< Derived0, Derived1, Derived2 > ) `

Comment: @gomons Yes: the variant is a little more than just a union,  and this comes at the costs the overhead of an int.  I believe the goal of the OP is not to know the exact size, but manage a buffer of dynamic objects.  The variant solution adresses both needs.  If you'd want to do the same thing with a union, you'd need to take care of alignment, and most of all keep track of the active member of the union.

Comment: @Christophe, you are fight, +1 (=

Answer (score 3):

Works only for POD classes:

```
union AllDerived {
    Derived0 _0;
    Derived1 _1;
    Derived2 _2;
};

static const size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE = sizeof(AllDerived);
static const size_t NUMBER_OF_POOLS = 10;
char buffer[NUMBER_OF_POOLS * LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE];
```

And this solution works not only for POD:

```
template <int Value1, int Value2>
struct static_max {
    static const int value = (Value1 < Value2) ? Value2 : Value1 ;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct TypeList {
    typedef T Head;
    typedef U Tail;
};

class NullType {};

template
<
    typename T1  = NullType, typename T2  = NullType, typename T3  = NullType,
    typename T4  = NullType, typename T5  = NullType, typename T6  = NullType,
    typename T7  = NullType, typename T8  = NullType, typename T9  = NullType,
    typename T10 = NullType, typename T11 = NullType, typename T12 = NullType,
    typename T13 = NullType, typename T14 = NullType, typename T15 = NullType,
    typename T16 = NullType, typename T17 = NullType, typename T18 = NullType
>
struct MakeTypelist
{
private:
    typedef typename MakeTypelist
    <
        T2 , T3 , T4 ,
        T5 , T6 , T7 ,
        T8 , T9 , T10,
        T11, T12, T13,
        T14, T15, T16,
        T17, T18
    >
    ::Result TailResult;

public:
    typedef TypeList<T1, TailResult> Result;
};

template<>
struct MakeTypelist<>
{
    typedef NullType Result;
};

template<typename TList>
struct MaxTypeSize;

template <>
struct MaxTypeSize<NullType> {
    enum { value=0 };
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct MaxTypeSize<TypeList<T,U>> {
    enum { value = static_max<sizeof(T), MaxTypeSize<U>::value>::value };
};

typedef MakeTypelist<Derived0, Derived1, Derived2>::Result AllTypes;
static const size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE = MaxTypeSize<AllTypes>::value;
static const size_t NUMBER_OF_POOLS = 10;
char buffer[NUMBER_OF_POOLS * LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE];
```

Here we use type list and compile-type max function. Type list implementation you can find in [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) library. Compile-time function MaxTypeSize calculate maximum type size in list.

Comment: This will compile/work, but only because the derived classes re POD types. If you give any of the derived classes a non-default constructor, you'll get a compiler error if you don't have C++11 support enabled. I knew this when I asked the question, so I should have used examples that would fail with this union approach. Thanks though!

Comment: @gomons This will compile with C++11.  For C++03 it won't compile as soon as you put a string as member, for the reason Matt explained.  See this code snippet as demonstration:  http://ideone.com/0CjYW2  (you can copy paste it with C++11 option and then it will work).

Comment: @gomons +1 ;-) now it becomes interesting !  Could you just explain how to extend this approach if there's ùore than 3 derived classes ?

Comment: @Christophe, I copy some code from loki, so now you can create TypeList with 18 elements.

Comment: Actually it is kind of magic for me that I don't understand enough, but I can use it

Answer (score 0):

I know OP said C++03, but I was looking for a solution for C++1x and thought I'd put it here for anyone searching.

```
#include <algorithm>

static const size_t LARGEST_CHILD_SIZE = std::max({sizeof(Derived0), 
                                                   sizeof(Derived1), 
                                                   sizeof(Derived2)});
```